# Mulesoft - problem with azure-service-bus-messaging:message-listener

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, enqueue

I need your help with an issue I'm facing while configuring the "azure-service-bus-messaging:message-listener" component. This is because, when it receives 10,000 or more messages from the queue, it enters a "zombie" state. I've tried limiting the number of messages with the "prefetchCount" property of the connector and restricting the threads by setting the parameter in the parent flow component, "maxConcurrency."

```
<flow name="azure_observer_mule_logger_system_api_flow" doc:id="" maxConcurrency="200" initialState="started">

    <azure-service-bus-messaging:message-listener doc:name="Message listener" doc:id="" destinationName="nombre-cola" ackMode="MANUAL" config-ref="Azure_Service_Bus_Messaging_Connector_Config" prefetchCount="200" numberOfConsumers="200">

      <reconnect frequency="5000" count="3" />

    </azure-service-bus-messaging:message-listener>
```

What do you recommend to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

If requirements allow you to process one message at a time, disable buffered mode on listener.
If not, remove listener and use scheduler to trigger receiving messages in batch - make sure that you handle failures because batch mode only supports immediate ACK.